# Nivo slider transition

Tags: javascript, magento, nivo-slider

I have the nivo slider added into my Magento theme on the homepage, at the moment it is showing a load of random effects.

I just want it to show one effect where all the slides will slide in from the right, appear on the screen for 3 seconds and then slide out to the left with the new one sliding in from the right in a continuous manner.

I'm not very good with javascript so I am hoping someone can help me out on this the nivo [javascript is here in pastebin](http://pastebin.com/EwHq0wcr)

Answer (score 3):

You should us **slideInRight** effect, there's nothing to change with the nivo's .js file. Just use this

`$('#slider').nivoSlider({effect:'slideInRight'});`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Im not sure where I can add this though currently the slider is added through a CMS page in Magento using this `<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider"><a href="#"><img src="{{media url=slider/large1.jpg}}" alt="" /></a> <a href="#"><img src="{{media url=slider/large2.jpg}}" alt="" /></a><a href="#"><img src="{{media url=slider/large3.jpg}}" alt="" /></a><a href="#"><img src="{{media url=slider/large4.jpg}}" alt="" /></a><a href="#"><img src="{{media url=slider/large5.jpg}}" alt="" /></a></div>`

Comment: This is the html. Where is the js where the slider is initialized.

Comment: Im not sure it uses a 1 column template from Magento which just calls the page's content which is above and in my header it just calls - jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js. I also have a jquery.nivo.slider.js file but can't see it being called in anywhere but it does have the settings at the bottom but when I change them it makes no difference.

Answer (score 3):

its work for me. let it try  add `data-transition` effect name `slideInRight` or `slideInLeft`

```
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider" width="480" >
     <img src="slider/1.jpg" alt="" data-transition="slideInLeft" />
     <img src="slider/4.jpg" alt="" data-transition="slideInRight" />
</div>
```

also can try in JS

```
$(window).load(function() {
     $('#slider').nivoSlider({effect:'slideInRight'});    
});
```

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436159/how-to-change-nivo-slider-easing#6436445) :

You can choose from the following effects:

- sliceDown
- sliceDownLeft
- sliceUp
- sliceUpLeft
- sliceUpDown
- sliceUpDownLeft
- fold
- fade
- random
- slideInRight
- slideInLeft
- boxRandom
- boxRain
- boxRainReverse
- boxRainGrow
- boxRainGrowReverse

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the jquery.nivo.slider.js file, if you open this file in notepad and go to line-348, you should see the following code:-

```
// Generate random effect
        if(settings.effect === 'random'){
            anims = new Array('sliceDownRight','sliceDownLeft','sliceUpRight','sliceUpLeft','sliceUpDown','sliceUpDownLeft','fold','fade',
            'boxRandom','boxRain','boxRainReverse','boxRainGrow','boxRainGrowReverse');
            currentEffect = anims[Math.floor(Math.random()*(anims.length + 1))];
            if(currentEffect === undefined) { currentEffect = 'fade'; }
        }
```

In the code change the following line, (make sure to remove all the other effects stated in this line)

anims = new Array ('**slideInRight**');

and also the last line

if(currentEffect === undefined) {currentEffect = '**slideInRight**'}

Now you should have a single transition effect.

Answer (score -1):

in **webpart.cs** file

```
img.addAtribute("data-transition","slideInRight");
```